# How can i bybass service worker cache?

Tags: caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a **progressive web appliacation**. on the home page i have a loging modal. If a user logs in the application reloads and now instead of the login button the server renders the user profile. now the problem am experiencing is that when i implemented the pwa, It caches the homepage and everything in it so the new page from the server is not rendered after the user logs in.
My application backend is in **Nodejs(REST API)** and is use javascript to consume the api but i use **ejs** to render the pages.  How can i solve this?. For now i decided not to cache the homepage where i have the login modal. After  doing this i realized the application is now not meeting PWA installation requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache everything in the service worker.
When you need to display different content for an authenticated user vs unauthenticated user you can render that as needed either in the UI code or even in the service worker.

A common example would be to show/hide the login, logout and profile link in the header. This is all doable with a few lines of code as the page is loaded.
These examples are mostly classList.[add|remove|toggle]. The profile might use a simple template and setting the innerHTML of a wrapper.
It is not that complicated in the end, I do this all the time for applications.

Comment: Thanks for that. I decided to use the network first approach when using the service workers

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you shouldn't configure your service worker to cache your normal HTML. Instead, you can use a service worker that will always go to the network when online, and will display custom "Sorry, you're offline" HTML when there's a navigation request that fails.

Here's a live example of following this pattern:

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/custom-offline-page/

Doing this will is sufficient to meet the "add to homescreen" PWA installation requirements.